# How to disable a SQL Server view?

Tags: sql-server, view, disable

I have a view in SQL Server which is getting data from some remote database. But my "user" does not have permission to get that database.

So whenever I am executing or firing select query with that view, I get some errors:

> Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Procedure XYZ, Line 32 [Batch Start Line 0]
>   Invalid object name 'REMOTE_DB.dbo.Remote_Table_Name'.
>
> Msg 4413, Level 16, State 1, Line 6
>   Could not use view or function 'XYZ' because of binding errors.

I want to know how we can enable/disable a view in SQL Server like a trigger. I'd like to be able to disable a view while I am doing any script execution over my database and will enable again.

FYI, I can't drop or delete that view for now because of some dependencies. So I only want temporary disabling of view.

Comment: You can't "disable" a view. It's not a trigger. If you don't want to use that view, don't use it in your SQL queries.

Comment: off-topic - belongs on [dba](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sql-server). Perhaps changing the permissions temporarily would suffice.

Comment: @Larnu, actually I am deploying 'dacpac' from SSDT to SQL Server and we are not using this View in any query. So while executing dacpac this VIEW is automatically executing and I am getting this error.

Comment: Then remove it from the dacpac.

Comment: A view doesn't "execute" - you **select** from it ....

Comment: To hell they don't.  The only types of views "don't execute"  when you select from them are "Indexed Views".  Normal views are not "materialized" an each reference to them, even if in the same query, will cause them to execute for every reference.